# spam from isp unknown.unknown

Tags: spam, traffic

My website is getting fake/spam traffic i tracked the ISP of these spam visits and there were 2 one of them were amazon's and the other were unknown.unknown

i did block all the amazon's ips in the firewall which stopped the traffic from it but have no idea what to do with unknown.unknown and what is this : http://prntscr.com/dgazij ( this is only of one hour )

how can it is even possible to have this as name of and internet service provider ?

the traffic is pretty bad and still going on, please any suggestion where i need to look or what i should do to stop it ?

Thanks

Comment: I did the same as the answer below if you want me to post my .htaccess and robots.txt file let me know and i'll post it for you to review. You will have to amend it for your use. Also if your using a wordpress site your want some additional protection in there, what is your website url?

Answer (score 0):

i ended up blocking all known bots ips with .htaccess which include amazone, ovh , tor and couple of more which made the spam traffic less by 80% and then the sender gave up

robots.txt also helped to block bad crawlers